# Django Count - filter the set being counted

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have this situation

```
class Video(models.Model):
    public = models.BooleanField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children')
```

I want to get a list of videos ordered by the number of children they have that are public.

I can do something like:

```
video.objects.annotate(children_count=Count('children')).order_by('children_count')
```

which gives me a set of videos in order of number of children - however this counts both private and public children. How do I only count public children?

I want something like this:

```
video.objects.annotate(children_count=Count('children' where children.public=True)).order_by('children_count')
```

which of course doesn't work as is

Answer (score 0):

How About

```
Video.objects.filter(public=True).
annotate(children_count=Count('children')).order_by('children_count')
```

Read more about it here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses

Comment: @GlynJackson I've not written one before, so I'm not sure as to how that one would pan out.

Comment: this looks for public videos it doesn't ensure that the children are also public.

Answer (score 0):

What worked was:

Video.objects.filter(children__public=True).annotate(children_count=Count('children')).order_by('children_count')